# Fancybox-3 is causing URL issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I've just begun a basic HTML page to get to grips with implementing `Fancybox-3` into my sites code. When I select either of the two thumbnails, their full size IMG appears (as expected), but, another `'C:/'` appears in the URL! This is compounded each time I select the `'Next'` or `'Back'` arrow on either image, as this inserts yet another, `'C:/'` into the ever expanding URL.

> e.g. file:///C:/C:/C:/C:/Users/Peter%20Johnstone/Desktop/...

Comment: Bet you would not have this problem if you tested properly, over HTTP(S), instead of just loading the files via the local file system ...

Comment: It is not a good idea to view html files directly in the browser and to use local file system (ajax and other functionality will not work)

Comment: Thanks. Can I just add that I'm a newby here. I asked the question because I wanted to know WHY it was happening, so that I can learn to fix the issue.  If you say I would not get an issue if I uploaded it, then fine. But I would still like to know why there's a fail so I can avoid repeating it in the future. I have never had this problem when testing pages from the Local System.

Comment: _“I asked the question because I wanted to know WHY it was happening, so that I can learn to fix the issue”_ - then you will have to delve deeper into the internals of that script, and do some debugging. _“If you say I would not get an issue if I uploaded it, then fine.”_ - can’t say for sure, but that would be my guess. If you want anything more than that, then the first necessary step would be for you to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I will try and dig deeper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me the issue lies in the fact that your are probably running your local website with localhost.

The solution is to create a virtual host on your machine so that you can have a functional web root.

You don't mention which technology you are using, in case it's Apache, have a look on one way to do it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356314/local-url-for-apache-errordocument-directive-not-working-in-htaccess-file/47314120#47314120).

Comment: Thank you for your help, Brac. I knew nothing about MAMP before this thread and it is now providing a solution to my problem.